# How do I install the LINC software switch?

Tags: ubuntu

Even following the [LINC-switch](https://github.com/FlowForwarding/LINC-Switch) instructions, I was unable to get LINC and Erlang working correctly. How can I solve this?

Comment: You can find more on the page https://github.com/FlowForwarding/LINC-Switch/blob/internals-oe-doc/README.md#erlang

Answer (score 0):

Before installing the LINC software switch, you need to install the Erlang language. However, I was able to install with only one version of the Erlang. Because of the lack of support for the Erlang+LINC installation, the following steps are necessary in order to correctly install Erlang and the LINC software switch:

1) On Ubuntu, we must accomplish some pre-requisites before installing Erlang:

```
# apt-get install gcc wget make autoconf openssl libssl0.9.8 libssl-dev libncurses5 libncurses5-dev
```

2) As I said to use LINC you need to have an Erlang runtime installed on your machine. Forget about the APT-GET erlang version for UBUNTU. It has a bug that will not permit you run LINC. You must donwload the R16B source version from the Erlang website:

```
http://www.erlang.org/downloads/R16B
```

3) When your system environment is ready download the sources from erlang.org. Unpack, compile and install:

```
./configure (as non-root)
make (as non-root)
make install (as root)
```

4) To build the LINC switch you need to install the following additional libraries and tools:

```
# apt-get install git-core bridge-utils libpcap0.8 libpcap-dev libcap2-bin uml-utilities
```

5) When your environment is set up you are ready to build and run LINC. Clone this git repository:

```
% git clone https://github.com/FlowForwarding/LINC-Switch
```

6) Extract the LINC-Switch, open the folder and create a configuration file based on an example that comes with the switch:

```
 cp rel/files/sys.config.orig rel/files/sys.config
```

7) Compile everything

```
 make
```

8) Start LINC switch in console mode:

```
 % rel/linc/bin/linc console
```